# Where is aerospike.conf file located on mac?

Tags: database, aerospike

I am using Aerospike for the first time on mac and I want to create namespace in it. My colleague told me that I need to make namespace in aerospike.conf file. Can someone please tell me its path on mac?

Comment: Mr Jon, Please go ahead try your answer on mac. It is not as simple as you suggested. 
Next time thoroughly try the solution before you answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vagrant (and I do not see other standard Mac options on the Aerospike's site), then Jon Surrel's answer above is correct: your conf file is under /etc/aerospike/ folder. Just do "vagrant ssh" into the vagrant box.

Answer (score 1):

aerospike.conf is only relevant to a server install and the server is not certified to run on Mac, only Linux.  The Aerospike tools do run on Mac but the aerospike.conf is not relevant to the tools.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the [docs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/) says:

```
/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf
```